# CSS to prevent an inline item from increasing parent items size?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a `<span>` element inside a `<td>` cell. I'm trying to figure out what CSS rules to use to force the `<span>` content to wrap to a new line instead of causing the `<td>` item to expand.

Sample code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <p>This should set cell width</p>
        <span>This longer line should wrap at the length of the above 
        &lt;p&gt; element width.</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the table width isn't 100% of it's parent container. I don't want to force the table to a certain size, I just want to exclude this particular content from being included in the table's size calculations.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: No way to limit it.  If you don't specify the column width or table width, or span width it will expand. What criteria would determine it to not expand?

Comment: @Dan - it should expand until it is as wide as the widest sibling in the block, then wrap. Seems simple enough to me...

Comment: No way to bind the width of your span to the width of your paragraph that I know of in CSS - without specifying the width of your paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't do so only with CSS. As you mentioned it can be done by JS. Try have a look at my quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/a9dhC/

Is it what you expected?